# Scientific computing oriented logging library?

Tags: c++, logs

We are looking for a simple library to help us with logging the state of a real-time numerical system. For now, we use a simple csv-like format, but are interested in logging more things, faster, and in a more flexible way:

- At each step (a few ms), we need to log about ~100 floating point numbers.
- As the state of the system evolves the number of columns (and their header) will change a few times.

Is there any product that would help us with this ? So basically, a column-oriented, flexible schema, binary format.

We are not fundamentally opposed to querying a distant endpoint, but we'd rather not have to send data over the network.

We thought about rolling our own, by inserting new headers in a single file whenever there's a change in the columns, but we would then need to handle by ourselves the reprocessing...

This library should also ideally have python bindings for later data exploration.

Comment: Since you want to exploit the data in python, you might look at [picklingtools](http://www.picklingtools.com/) which seems to be a C++ library compatible with python [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) (version 2, binary). That page also links to a pdf describing the resulting binary format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, we rolled out our (hopefully) temporary solution:

- Serialize all our objects using [flatbuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/)
- Write them to disk in a separate thread
- A small tool to bring the data back out as a CSV / DBMS file

We looked at:

- [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/): great performance, has streaming to disk, but not usable as a library unfortunately.
- [WhiteDB](http://whitedb.org/): performance is not so great, no streaming to disk and needs to manually select the amount of available memory.
- [Akumuli](http://akumuli.org/): performance looks great, is usable as a library! Unfortunately, it is still very unstable (I couldn't get it to build a new volume without segfaulting).
- [Rosbag](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag): performance is poor, does not have built-in support for streaming to disk (but it can be done by threading), has a lot of good ROS-enabled tooling.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're asking for is a DBMS (possibly with streaming functionality, or schema-less) - and definitely not a logging library (such as [these](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/31780/15631)).

Logging libraries don't generally involve columns (except with fields such as the timestamp, thread id, log level etc. - that is, log output formatting); it is not intended for you to log large amounts of data; log formats should not evolve; etc.

Comment: That's an interesting thought, I'll try to tinker with a few products. I found that InfluxDB looks pretty good, but not sure how to get the data back out.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want an DBMS; it'll be too slow. You want a time-series database. Start with InfluxDB. https://www.influxdata.com/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but Influx can not be used as a library as far as I can tell...

Comment: Don't use it as a library. Just spawn it or require it as a dependency.